# How to reference a Hibernate @ManyToOne association without laoding it from the database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have created some Hibernate mappings with Hibernate 4.3.8.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ErrorEntity.TABLE_ID)
@XmlRootElement(name = ErrorEntity.XML_ROOT_TAG)
public class ErrorEntity {

    /**
   * 
   */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8083918635458543738L;

    public static final String TABLE_ID = "Error";
    public static final String ERRORCODE = "error_code";
    public static final String ENV_ID = "envid";

    private Integer error_code;
    private Integer envId;
    private EnvironmentEntity environment;

    public ErrorEntity() {

    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = ErrorEntity.ERRORCODE)
    public Integer getError_code() {
        return error_code;
    }

    public void setError_code(Integer errorcode) {
        this.error_code = errorcode;
    }

    @Column(name = ErrorEntity.ENV_ID)
    public Integer getEnvId() {
        return envId;
    }

    public void setEnvId(Integer envId) {
        this.envId = envId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = ErrorEntity.ENV_ID, referencedColumnName = EnvironmentEntity.ENV_ID, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public EnvironmentEntity getEnvironment() {
        return environment;
    }

    public void setEnvironment(EnvironmentEntity environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

}
```

As you can see the mapping property ENV_ID is mapped twice.

Thisway I thought I would be able to set the JoinColumn value without querying the database to get the mapped object because I have the JoinColumn value at this point.

The value of ENV_ID is written correctly to the database but if I query this ErrorEntity later and try to get the EnvironmentEntity the reference is null.

```
ErrorEntity error = (ErrorEntity) criteria.uniqueResult();
System.out.println(error.getEnvironment().getName());
```

getEnvironment() returns null.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

---

Edit

It was working like expected to create a new object with the PK set.

Now I have a special situation where it does not work.
I need to reference another object where the joincolumn is not the PK. I know that the value i will join on is unique but there are also some duplicate values i will not join on.

However Hibernate seems to be unable to map this relationship automatically.

```
ErrorEntity error = new ErrorEntity();

SignalEntity signal = new SignalEntity();
signal.setName(signalName);

error.setSignal(signal);
```

The problem is that I do not have the signalID (PK) in that situation. The other idea would be to query the db but thats too slow.

I tried to create an composite PK with 3 columns but this breaks the logic at another place.

Is it possible to create two independent PK's?

Comment: Can you post the ddl of ErrorEntity table?

Comment: envId schould be mapped once?? why it is mapped twice?

Comment: Also can you post EnvironmentEntity. And when you do a fetch are you getting value for getEnvId()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ErrorEntity` has two `ErrorEntity.ENV_ID` mappings, which unless you use [@MapsId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) then it's a configuration issue.

You should have an `env_id` column in `EnvironmentEntity` table and just the:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = ErrorEntity.ENV_ID, referencedColumnName = EnvironmentEntity.ENV_ID, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public EnvironmentEntity getEnvironment() {
    return environment;
}
```

mapping in `ErrorEntity`.

My suggestion is to remove this:

```
@Column(name = ErrorEntity.ENV_ID)
public Integer getEnvId() {
    return envId;
}
```

To set the envId directly without querying the database and request the whole EnvironmentEntity, you can do something like this:

```
errrorEntity.setEnvironment(new EnvironmentEntity());
errrorEntity.getEnvironment().setEnvId(envId);
```

This is not a JPA standard requirement but Hibernate supports it.

Comment: Yes you are right that getEnvId is nonsense at first glance but as I said i need a way to set the envId directly without querying the database and request the whole EnvironmentEntity.

Comment: Yes you can. You can even do something like this: `errrorEntity.setEnvironment(new EnvironmentEntity());errrorEntity.getEnvironment().setEnvId(envId);` and it will just work, without having to query the DB.

Comment: Wow thats new to me! I have written a post on the hibernate forum directly and have not got an answer after 3 weeks. Will try it :) many thanks